# return Element if exists using ternary operator by the shorten way as possible in JS

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to shorten the `myFx()` function without repeating `document.getElementById('myID')` ?
I just want to return the Element if it exists, if it doesn't, return "false".

The function is working well that manner, but I would like to know if there is any way to shorten it a little more.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myID">Hello World!</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFx(){

  return (document.getElementById('myID') === null) ? false : document.getElementById('myID');
  
}

myFx().innerHTML = "Goodbye Cruel World!";
```

Comment: What’s the point of this function, though, that just replaces `null` with `false`? If you’re doing it because you want to be able to set properties like `innerHTML` without getting an exception if the element doesn’t exist, you should `return document.getElementById('myID');` directly and do a manual `null` check on the caller’s side (some operations, like function calls, can use **optional chaining**). Setting properties on primitives will break in strict mode, which you should always use but which also isn’t optional inside an ES6 class, for example.

Comment: The point is that was the only way that my knowlege allowed at the moment. Now i learn that i can use a **nullish coalescing operator** in a shorten way like this `return document.getElementById('myID') ?? false;`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `return document.getElementById('myID') ?? false;` is a shorter way to arrive at the same problem. What I’m saying is that `false.innerHTML = "stuff"` throws an exception anyway when used in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and you can’t avoid strict mode in some cases.

Comment: Ok, i will investigate more about. But for this project i think is enought... By the way, how can i use the **strict mode** in this example? TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
function myFx() {
  return document.getElementById('myID') ?? false;

}

myFx().innerHTML = "Goodbye Cruel World!";
```

```html
<div id="myID">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: It Works!! I had already tried with **nullish coalescing operator** but the very wrong way like this `return (document.getElementById('myID') === null) ?? false;`. Now i understood, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @c0m1t is correct, just be aware that this might not work in older browsers. I am not sure if it's still a real issue today, but anyway .. here is solution which should work even in ancient browsers.

```
function myFx(){
  var element = document.getElementById('myID');
  return element || false;
}

myFx().innerHTML = "Goodbye Cruel World!";
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative way. I tested `return document.getElementById('myID') ?? false;` on chrome, edge, mozilla, safari (lastest  versions) and are working welll.